# SWIFT "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Tags: ios, json, swift, codable

This is my first-time question.
I thought I did everything correctly. Have I built my model wrong? I'm not sure how to fix this error.
This is my code, after the correct model I want to pass the data to the table:

```
func createJSON() {
    if let url = URL(string: "https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=apple&from=2020-11-15&to=2020-11-15&sortBy=popularity&apiKey=c5722efe6e65432fb5c116d3e1403dca") {
        
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
            
            var result: NewsResult?
            do {
                result = try JSONDecoder().decode(NewsResult.self, from: data)
            } catch {
                print("error masage: \(error)")
            }
            guard let finalResult = result else { return }
            
            print(finalResult.status)
            print(finalResult.totalResults)
//             print(finalResult.articles)
            
//            let newNews = finalResult.artiscles
//            self.newsApple.append(contentsOf: newNews)
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}


//    MARK: - Model Data Source

struct NewsResult:Codable {
    let status: String
    let totalResults: Int // totalResults
    let articles: [articles]
}

struct articles:Codable {
    let author: String // articles[0].author
    let title: String
    let description: String
    let url:String
    let urlToImage:String
    let publishedAt: String
    let content: String
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written the model code that was not mapping correctly with JSON resultant. Try replacing your model structure with the following code:

```
struct NewsResult: Codable {
    var status: String?
    var totalResults: Int?
    var articles: [Article]?
}

struct Article: Codable {
    var source: Source?
    var author: String?
    var title: String?
    var articleDescription: String?
    var url: String?
    var urlToImage: String?
    var publishedAt: String?
    var content: String?
}

struct Source: Codable {
    var id : String?
    var name: String?
}
```

Comment: @Sebastian If this works for you, please accept the answer so that it can be helpful for others if they face a similar kind of issue.

Comment: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score"

Comment: Ok got it! You can mark it as the correct answer by adding a tick mark for the answer as well.